# Probability of occurrence of random variable chosen from Normal Distribution

Tags: matlab, probability, normal-distribution

I was just wondering, with the code below, how would I determine the probability of occurrence associated with one of the random variables that are chosen. For example, if a particular variable is chosen for new_E11, how would I know its probability of occurrence from the Normal distribution?

```
function [new_E11, new_E22] = elasticmodulusrng()

new_E11 = normrnd(136e9,9.067e9,[1 1]);

new_E22 = normrnd(8.9e9,2.373e9,[1 1]);

while new_E11<=136e9-3*9.067e9 && new_E11>=136e9+3*9.067e9
        new_E11 = normrnd(136e9,9.067e9,[1 1]);
end

while new_E11<=8.9e9-3*2.373e9 && new_E11>=8.9e9+3*2.373e9
        new_E22 = normrnd(8.9e9,2.373e9,[1 1]);
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Its probabilty of occurrence is always 0, because it's a continuous random variable. Maybe you mean its probability _density_?

Comment: I suspect there is a typo in your code. The second `while` should be testing for `new_E22` not `new_E11`.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, its the probability density I am after, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of any *specific* value is zero (well, really about 1 part in 2^64... that's how many different floating point numbers there are since they are represented by a 64 bit binary; and they are not equally probable so the answer is more complicated than that).

A better question is "what is the probability *density*" - which can be described as the limit of

```
P(x - dx < X < x + dx)
----------------------
        2 * dx
```

This is in fact the definition of your "probability density function" or PDF. In your case, you are using the normal distribution with a mean mu and standard deviation sigma, then

```
pdf(X) = exp(-(X-mu)*(X-mu) / (2 * sigma * sigma)) / (sqrt(2.0*pi) * sigma)
```

If you *really* wanted the answer to your original question, you would look at the smallest delta (one least significant bit in the mantissa) of the X value for the value you are interested in. That would be your delta X, and you could then compute the actual answer (warning - not only would it be tiny, it might be hard to compute this without running into significant rounding errors. Would be hard.)

Further thought:

You test for the limit of the value to be within +- 3 sigma, and keep going until it is. That means that you artifically increase the probability very slightly - since your value is always from a particular part of the range (for which the total probability is less than 1), you need to multiply the PDF by `(1/p)` where `p` is the integral of the standard normal distribution from `-3` to `3`, or `0.9973`. So in your case the above formula would underestimate the probability by `0.27%`.

**suggestion** a couple of style suggestions for your code. Consider the following (gives equivalent results to your code):

```
function [new_E11, new_E22] = elasticmodulusrng()
  % returns randomly distributed modulus 
  % keeping the value within +- 3 standard deviations
  % identify the constants up front
  mean11 = 136e9;
  stdv11 = 9.067e9;
  mean22 = 8.9e9;
  stdv11 = 2.373e9;

  % compute the values
  new_E11 = normRandLimit(mean11, stdv11, [-3 3]);
  new_E22 = normRandLimit(mean22, stdv22, [-3 3]);

function rr = normRandLimit(m, s, b)
% helper function in the same file
% returns a normally distributed random variate
% with mean m, standard deviation s
% within limits [mean + b(1)*s,  mean + b(2)*s]

  while true 
    rr = randn(1); % doesn't need statistics toolbox - scale later
    if( rr > b(1) && rr < b(2) )
      break;  % found acceptable value
    end
  end
  % now apply scaling:
  rr = rr * s + m;
```

Things to note about this:

1. "magic numbers" have a sensible name, and are all at the top of the code
2. Computation of the "random number within limits" is relegated to a separate function
3. Using `randn` rather than `normrnd` (so no need to tie up statistics toolbox license)
4. Compute scaling after "good number" was computed
5. Repeated code has been eliminated
6. It is more obvious what is going on from the structure (and the comments)

All of this adds up to "better" code - in the sense that it's easier to debug, maintain. And when you see your own code in six months time, you can still read it...

Comment: @LuisMendo - thanks. I should have normalized of course. Fixed.

Comment: @Floris Thank you very much! Your code is very useful as well. I was just wondering, if I am artificially increasing the probability by choosing a fixed interval, surely I should be multiplying the PDF with a number that is smaller than 1, given that 1/p is greater than 1? I am sorry, I'm just a bit confused about this bit.

Comment: @Jojo - Think about it this way: If you toss a coin, you have a 50% chance of getting heads. If you decide "I will reject tails" (the equivalent of 'I reject values greater than 3 sigma away', but more extreme), then the probability your process will yield heads goes up to 100%. You have to multiply 0.5 by (1/0.5) to get to that answer. Make sense?

Comment: @Floris Thanks! I see what you mean.

Comment: @jojo - is the answer to your original question now clear, or do you need further clarification? If your question is now answered, you might want to mark it as such - that way other people won't spend time trying to come up with other answers. There's a little checkmark next to the answer for that purpose...

Comment: @Floris I've just thought about this a little bit more and I was wondering, if I wanted to know the probability of occurrence of a number in terms of the "original distribution", being chosen from the "truncated distribution", I wouldn't need to multiply my truncated distribution PDF with anything would I? Thanks!

Comment: @Jojo it's a funny thing. The probability of a certain number (within the limits) on the first roll is indeed unchanged - but since you might hit a "tail of the distribution" and sample again, the probability of that number is a little higher. If your first probability was `p` and the tails are a fraction `f` (meaning probability `f` that you sample again), then the total chance of getting the number is `p + f*p + f*f*p + ...` = `p * (1 + f + f^2 + ...)` = `p / (1 - f)` (geometric series). Which is the same formula as before.

Comment: @Floris Thanks again! May I just ask how `p/(1-f)` is equivalent to our previous multiplicative constant of `(1/p) = (1/0.9973)`. Sorry for asking so many questions, I am struggling with this concept slightly.

Comment: @Jojo I am sorry I changed the meaning of `p` in the mean time (comes from writing snippets at different times). In my answer, `p` was the probability of picking a random number between the limits. In my comment, that was `1-f` (`f` being the probability of falling outside the limits). In my comment `p` was the value of the PDF... So if `PDF -> p` and `p -> (1-f)` then `PDF/p -> p/(1-f)` . You're probably even more confused now...

Comment: @Floris Thanks. I understand the last statement and am now just confused by the fact that I would need to scale the truncated distribution by the same factor i.e. `(1/p) = (1/0.09973)` as I would scale the original distribution.

Comment: @Floris For example, even based on the coin tossing example you provided, if I wanted to know the probability of occurrence of a sample from my original distribution, given I now have a truncated distribution why would I look to multiply with `(1/0.5)` here? Thanks!

Comment: The scaling happens if you are interested in the probability that the **process** yields a value. In the case of the coin, "rejecting `tails` until you throw `heads` gives 100% probability of heads, not 50%. The probability of an individual throw being heads is still 50%...

Comment: @Floris Sorry for bringing this up again, but I just want to go back to my orignial question quickly. I've just been talking to my professor who said the following: "68% of the expected values are within [mu-sigma,mu+sigma] does not necessarily mean that every value within this range is equally probable. He says that I need to substitute x,mu and sigma into the PDF to get the Probability of x. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. You need to substitute the values into the equation I gave in the first place. The adjustment of (1/(1-f)) was just a "refinement". It appears I confused you by adding that detail, for which I apologize. But note - the probability of any value is zero. The probability of a value in an infinitesimally small range `dx` is `pdf * dx`. This is an important distinction but crucial for understanding probability density, and if your professor doesn't appreciate the difference (or has not explained it), he/she is not doing a very good job.